# Passing arguments to threaded listener

Tags: c#, tcp, filestream

I'm having server-clients applications. The server and clients can send and receive files using TCP and stream. The file transfer is handled in a listener which has it's own thread in my class like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));
    thread.Start();
}
```

And the Listen method (simplified):

```
private static void Listen()
{
    using (TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient())
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("fullFilePath.ext", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            // writing stream here
        }
    }
}
```

I send the file stream using (simplified):

```
public void SendFile(string destination, int transferPort)
{
    using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(destination, transferPort))
    {
        using (NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
        {
            // read bytes, write, and flush here
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I cannot figure out how to pass arguments so that Listen() can have 'dynamic' arguments I can pass to it.
For example, "fullFilePath.ext" would need to be dynamic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems very unclear what you are trying to accomplish here. What kind of parameters would you want to pass to SendFile and how would they dynamically effect Listen?

Comment: @JesseCarter, the idea is to be able to change "fullFilePath.ext" as a dynamic value in the Listen() method. But as the method is started as a thread, I'm not sure how I can achieve that.
I would need the SendFile()'s 'destination' argument to be passed to Listen() somehow.

Comment: Using `ThreadStart` is obsolete. Pass it a lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish and unfortunately it is not possible in the way that you're describing. When doing communication across a network connection, data is sent in bytes which need to be put back together on the other side. Using serialization, you can send actual objects across the stream which can be put back together on the other end.

If you are primarily sending text files across the network and you want to preserve the file name, you might consider defining a simple class:

```
public class TransportFileInfo() {
    string FileName { get; set; }
    string FileContents { get; set; }
}
```

In your listener thread, you would receive the bytes corresponding to a serialized TransportFileInfo and then deserialize that back to it's object form. At that point you would have access to FileName and FileContents to direct your output stream appropriately.

If you do some googling for C# binary serialization I'm sure you will find information that will be useful to you.

Comment: I'm sending XML, XLS and other file formats. Would that work too?
I'll check out for information on binary serialization anyway, thanks Jesse!

Comment: You might need to define different types depending on your different use cases but the main thing to take away is that network communication is typically done with some kind of serialization process on either end for flexibility in the information that you send. For text based file types you would most likely be able to send them using a simple class similar to the one I defined.